# SQLite format time range

Tags: sqlite, time, format, timespan

I have a time range in seconds and I want it to be in the `minutes'seconds` format.
Example: I have 90 seconds. I want them to be displayed as `1'30` minutes.

As I do not expect things to reach 1 hour, I came with the query on [a SQLite test web page](https://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle-5c66fcd9b0abb3yzjs6crt5k)

```
SELECT CAST (90/60 AS INTEGER) || "'" || CAST (90%60 AS INTEGER) FROM demo;
```

Is there a leaner way to do the same query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT strftime('%H:%M''%S', datetime(90, 'unixepoch'));
```

Comment: how can I remove the annoying zero on minutes?

Comment: You don't need the `datetime()`, btw. Just `strftime('blah', 90, 'unixepoch')` will do.

Comment: BTW, I am using `SELECT strftime("%M'%S", 90, 'unixepoch');` . Notice the omission of the `%H` part. It is why the leading 0 on minutes is annoying.